# iOS5: View disabled when revisited after previously returned and textFieldShouldEndEditing set to NO

Tags: ios5

I am working this on Xcode 4.3 target iOS5 for iPhone.

I have View B which is segue-ed from View A using simple button action. In View B have text field and I need this text field input validated. The validation rule is simple: if the text field is empty then textFieldShouldEndEditing return NO. The code is:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (![textField.text length]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This working fine. However, if I have not input anything and 'back' button is pushed (which is  pop the view controller) return to View A and I push the button again in View A to navigate to View B, the view B is completely disabled and I can not edit anything in the text field. This is not the case when the validation is not implemented OR always return YES. I also tried if I input something but textFieldShouldEndEditing always return NO;

I trace the code and notice that the textFieldShouldEndEditing is also fired if the controller pop-ed. I think the problem is something to do with thins setting textFieldShouldEndEditing set to YES or NO, but I completely confused.

Please help...

Comment: Log.d textfield length, once you enter into View B second time

Comment: the textField.text length is 0

Comment: So it should return NO in order to enable the editing am I right?

Comment: I am thinking if I can find out a state if the textFieldShouldEndEditing is fired due to pop/back, then I can always return YES in that case.

Comment: How about you explicitly call setEnable in viewDidLoad? or viewWillLoad in View B

Comment: if still does not work. I also tried explicitly becomeFirstResponder not working

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the view controller is the top view controller first:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (self == self.navigationController.topViewController)
        if (textField == self.confirmationCodeField)
            if (textField.text.length < kAuthCodeMinLength)
                return NO;

    return YES; // default
}
```